# I want to navigate to another page after hitting login button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am kind of new to web development and using angular. I have a login component from which I want to move on to another component after hitting LOGIN button. It is loading another component but the thing happening is that it loads the data of other component in the same page and also viewing previous login component too but i need it on other page.

index.html

```
<body>
    <app-loginpage>
        <div id="loader"><img src="assets/img/loaderpreview.svg"></div>
    </app-loginpage>

</body>
```

loginpage.component.html

```
<div class="text-center">
          <button (click)="redirect()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg loginbtn">
           Login
          </button>
<router-outlet *ngIf="loadcomponent"></router-outlet>
```

loginpage.component.ts

```
export class LoginpageComponent implements OnInit {
  private loadcomponent = false;
  name: string;
  password: any;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
redirect() {
      this.loadcomponent = true;
  }
```

app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes =[

{path:'',component:AdminLayoutComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'table',
    pathMatch: 'full',
 }, 
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module').then(m => m.AdminLayoutModule)
  }]
},
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'table'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want to load AdminLayoutComponent after hitting login button but on another page but its loading on same page. Here are the screenshots of the current behavior:

[This screenshot is while loading Login Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBd6l.png)

[This is after clicking login button. Marked in red is login Component and green is the component I want on other page not on the same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKbIv.png)

Sorry already if have been doing silly mistake.lol

Comment: Can you share a working stackblitz of the same so that it is easily reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `<router-outlet>` on the main app template (usually `app.component.html`), and render the `<app-loginpage>` only when not logged in. Something like:

**index.html**

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-loginpage *ngIf="!authenticated"></app-loginpage>
<router-outlet *ngIf="authenticated"></app-loginpage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting login and admin layout, and both enter by the router.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

**my-app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
// ......
const routes: Routes  = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: AdminLayoutComponent
    },
]
// ......
```

And then, you should resolve some questions:

1. How to detect the user is logged in already?
2. How to prevent user access the Admin layout when user is logged out? You can use angular router guards (see https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards).